# How to queryset inheritance model django?

Tags: python, django

I have models

```
class Parent(Model):
    pass

class Child1(Parent):
    att1 = CharField()

class Child2(Parent):
    att2 = CharField()

class Final(Model):
    parent = ForeignKey('Parent', related_name="final")
```

I need to queryset

```
Final.objects.filter(parent__att1='abc')
```

But just **Child1** inheritance **Parent** has **att1**. How to queryset **att1** in **Child1** not **Child2**?

Comment: You can query with `Final.objects.filter(parent__child1__att1='abc')`. Of course it will only look for `Final` objects that point to a `Child1` object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you, if I have a list of Model same Child1 inheritance from Parent, how to queryset. Maybe Final.objects.filter(parent_child1__att1='abc') | Final.objects.filter(parent_child3__att1='abc') | Final.objects.filter(parent_child4__att1='abc')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query with:

```
Final.objects.filter(parent__child1__att1='abc')
```

In Django model inheritance (of non-abstract models) is achieved by adding an implicit `OneToOneField` in the child model(s). We can thus use that relation by querying in *reverse*.

This will thus create a query that looks like:

```
SELECT final.*
FROM final
INNER JOIN parent ON final.parent_id = parent.id
INNER JOIN child1 ON parent.id = child1.parent_ptr_id
WHERE child1.att1 = 'abc'
```